# What is the correct JSON format for googles classroom.create?

Tags: node.js, json, google-api, google-classroom

Im trying to create a classroom using googles classroom API. Whenever run the classroom.create function I always receive the same error message. I'm using the JSON format from their docs but I just can't get it to work. I think I must be missing something.

This is the function:

```
async function listCourses(auth) {
const classroom = google.classroom({ version: 'v1', auth });
//Read data from JSON
let data = fs.readFileSync("class.json");
let course = JSON.parse(data);
//Try and create course
try {
    const res = await classroom.courses.create(course);
    console.log(res.data);
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
//List all current courses
classroom.courses.list({
    pageSize: 10,
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const courses = res.data.courses;
    if (courses && courses.length) {
        console.log('Courses:');
        courses.forEach((course) => {
            console.log(`${course.name} (${course.id})`);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No courses found.');
    }
});
```

}

This is the JSON:

```
{
"id": "157942918368",
"name": "English - 9Y",
"section": "Period 2",
"ownerId": "me",
"courseState": "ACTIVE"
```

}

This is the error message:

```
 code: 400,
 errors: [
{
  message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "name": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'name' could not be found in request message.\n` +
    `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "ownerId": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'ownerId' could not be found in request message.\n` +
    `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "courseState": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'courseState' could not be found in request message.\n` +
    `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "id": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'id' could not be found in request message.\n` +
    `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "section": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'section' could not be found in request message.`,
  reason: 'invalid'
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create new course using googleapis for Node.js.

### Modification points:

- At googleapis for Node.js, please put the request body to `resource` and/or `requestBody`.

  - I think that the reason of your error message is due to this.
- When `"id": "157942918368",` is used, an error of `Request contains an invalid argument.` occurs.
- When `"courseState": "ACTIVE"` is used, an error of `"@CourseStateDenied This user cannot create or transition courses into the requested state."` occurs.

  - "PROVISIONED" can be used in this case.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
const res = await classroom.courses.create(course);
```

#### To:

```
const res = await classroom.courses.create({ requestBody: course });
```

or

```
const res = await classroom.courses.create({ resource: course });
```

And also, please modify your request body as follows.

#### From:

```
{
  "id": "157942918368",
  "name": "English - 9Y",
  "section": "Period 2",
  "ownerId": "me",
  "courseState": "ACTIVE"
}
```

#### To:

```
{
  "name": "English - 9Y",
  "section": "Period 2",
  "ownerId": "me",
}
```

### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `const classroom = google.classroom({ version: 'v1', auth });` can be used for using the method of courses.create in Classroom API.

### References:

- [Method: courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create)
- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)